# Jquery datetimepicker opening first time at different position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I am using Jquery datetimepicker plugin [link here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

When I click on the field for first time, the datetimepicker is not opening near the field, something like below, the picker is way above the field.

[image: First Click]

When I close it and click on it second time and after, it is appearing in proper place. depicted below.

[image: Second Click and after]

This is weird, and when I set either timepicker or datepicker to false, the picker is working fine from the first click.

The code I used to construct the picker is below,

**HTML**

```
<input id="DateTimeFrom" type="text" class="widthAdjust" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#DateTimeFrom').datetimepicker({
          onShow:function( ct ){
           this.setOptions({
            maxDate:maximumDate, 
            maxTime:maximumTime
           })
          },
          mask : true
         });
```

I am not applying any CSS except for setting width to the field.

For `maximumDate` and `maximumTime` I performing some logic and setting to it, But I am pretty sure that the logic has no effect on this issue.

**EDIT**

I have my code in fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b6anz7t7/). but I couldnt link the datetimepicker js and css.

Any sort of guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Could you post your html/css or a jsFiddle? Chances are it is to do with the css `position` of it's parent container when you call it.

Comment: I can post the html and css but I cant link the datetimepicker js and css in jsfiddle

Comment: @JakeWhiteley I have put my css and html in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b6anz7t7/

Comment: I added the datepicker css js at: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7ouh4b3g/). From jQuery: `Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.` So if you remove the margin-left on the <main> element this works fine. The only way to sort this out is to dynamically set the `top` of the datepicker manually (bad plugin writing not accounting for this). I shall post my answer later.

Comment: @JakeWhiteley Thanks a lot, but even if i remove the margin-left on  <main>, it is not working. I will be waiting for your answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ouh4b3g/ - I got home and tried this on Chrome (newest version) and it mysteriously works fine. I was using Chrome earlier, so I am stumped.

Comment: I am blind on what is going on with this issue . :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `offset()` for datetimepicker

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    $('.xdsoft_noselect').css('top', $("#DateTimeFrom").offset().top + $("#DateTimeFrom").outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has no effect on issue